# Doubt on how to proceed with this PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve $$u_t = ku_{xx} + xe^t$$ where $0<x<\pi$ and $t>0$

$$u(0, t) = u(π, t) = 0 \quad , \quad t>0$$

$$u(x,0)=0 \quad, \quad 0<x<\pi$$

Attempt:

I began by separating variables $$u(x,t) = T(t)X(x)$$ and looked at the eigenvalue problem 
$$X'' + λX = 0$$
$$X(0) = X(π) = 0$$

The eigenvalues and the corresponding eigenfunctions are,

$$λ=n^2 \quad, \quad X_n(x)=\sin(nx)$$

I then set $$u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty T_n(t)\sin(nx)$$

I then tried to expand into Fourier Series but I got confused.

My main problem is dealing with the "$xe^t$" and help with that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello @user75399, welcome to Math.SE! To get better answers here we expect you to show a little of your thought on the problem, and more context. As the question stands it'll be harder to get the answers you expect. Also, try not to post questions like: "solve this", "prove that", it's something that we avoid as maximum as possible here. Welcome again and good luck.

Comment: Sorry about that, as you can seem I'm quite new to this community. Hopefully these changes are more helpful. Please let me know if there are any more problems. Thanks

Comment: No need to sorry! The intent of posting the comment is exactly to teach how to use this site. It's much better now. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You should represent your function as a series:
$$
xe^t=\sum_{m=1}^\infty f_m(t)\sin mx,
$$
where 
$$
f_m(t)=\frac{2 e^t}{\pi}\int_{0}^\pi x\sin mx\,{\rm d}x.
$$

After this you plug everything into your equation, and you will find a sequence of non-homogeneous linear ODE for $T_n(t)$ with zero initial conditions.